# S3 Presigned Url Callback

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to know if someone has uploaded something to generated public presigned url of S3? Like a callback that will trigger my servlet.

For example:

I created a presigned url from this [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html)

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider()); 

java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
long msec = expiration.getTime();
msec += 1000 * 60 * 60; // Add 1 hour.
expiration.setTime(msec);

GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey);
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.PUT); 
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);

URL url = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest); 

// Use the pre-signed URL to upload an object.
```

then, I give the `url` to someone and if that someone upload something to that `url`, the `http://example.com/upload` will be invoked with data from uploaded file.

Comment: https://github.com/gkarthiks/s3-presigned-url

Answer (score 3):

You can use [S3 event notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) to generate a notification. Look at the `ObjectCreated` event. The notifications can be filtered by the S3 prefix. (There are samples in the AWS documentation on the linked page.)